# Pass variable from one JavaScript callback anonymous function to another

Tags: javascript, jquery

As shown below, I am passing a variable from the `inputclass` callback to the `validate` callback.

Could it be done so without using a global variable so it will be local to the instance when applying the jQuery plugin to the given element?

```
$('#name').editable({
    inputclass: function() {
        globalVariable=this;
    },
    validate: function (value) {
        console.log(globalVariable);
        return 'pause';
    }
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cgym6m3v/3/)

Comment: you can try print out "this" in inputClass or validate function to see whether it refers to the configuration object itself. If it is (high chance), you can just put variable as a property of this, both of those functions will refer to the same configuration object

Comment: @PhuongNguyen  For this particular plugin, `this` within `inputclass` refers to a created `input` element while within `validate` refers to the originally element which the plugin was applied to.

Comment: try this: $.fn.editable.globalVariable . private for editable plugin.e.g: $.fn.editable.globalVariable =this;

Comment: Is this your plugin? If so, I think you should consider the option of passing that reference as a parameter to the validate callback.

Comment: @acontell  Not my plugin, but agree that it should be added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this in inputclass() and validate() are referring to different elements, it's a bit troublesome to share data. My idea is also using data(), but to pass data from inputclass() to validate(), you will need to travel up the dom from input that inputclass() refer to, up to .ui-tooltip, look for the element that validate() is referring to through id

```
$('#name').editable({
    inputclass: function(e, f) {
        $("a[aria-describedby=" + $(this).closest(".ui-tooltip").prop("id") + "]").data("shared", "somedata");
    },
    validate: function (value) {
        console.log("validate", $(this).data("shared"));
        return 'pause';
    }
});
```

Updated jsfiddle to demonstrate:

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cgym6m3v/4/)

Comment: Thanks Phuong,  Seems to work :)  Haven't fully tested, but each instance has its own dataset, right?  https://jsfiddle.net/cgym6m3v/5/

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using data attributes here to pass data.

```
$('#name').editable({
    inputclass: function() {
        var value = 'some value';
        $(this).data('input-value', value);
    },
    validate: function (value) {
        var inputValue = $(this).data('input-value');
        console.log(inputValue);
        return 'pause';
    }
});
```

This method will work only if you know the `inputClass` function gets called before `validate`

P.S: If you just want to pass `this`, there is absolutely no need for that, since it will be bind automatically in both functions.

Comment: Thanks Sriharsha,  `this` does not appear to be the same in the two callbacks, so I don't think this will work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define that variable outside the scope of functions:
Try this:

```
  var globalVariable;
    $('#name').editable({
        inputclass: function() {
            globalVariable='your value';
        },
        validate: function (value) {
            console.log(globalVariable);
            return 'pause';
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks Maverick.  Kind of what I was doing.  Problem is any time the plugin is applied on the page, it will share the same variable.